# What is this creature/character and what are its powers?

Tags: dc, character-identification, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

In *Legends of Tomorrow* season 5 episode 5 titled *'The Mortal Khanbat'*, Constantine calls a mysterious creature to heal him from lung cancer. What is this creature (character) and what are the powers that it possesses?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because episode 6 hasn't been aired yet, and given how little description of said character is given, I'm relatively sure the Future Works Policy applies.

Comment: It has aired. Yesterday in fact

Comment: Ah, then it's episode **5**, not 6. Will edit and retract my vote.

Comment: @Jenayah the episode that aired last night is indeed [episode 6](https://g.co/kgs/un8hDk), not 5.

Comment: @Remy OP said (on a deleted comment) they were referring to "Mortal Khanbat"? Which is I think the fifth one...?

Comment: It seems like some sources (e.g. [this Arrowverse wiki](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Season_5_(DC%27s_Legends_of_Tomorrow))) are considering the last episode of _Crisis on Infinite Earths_, which took place during the _Legends_ timeslot, to be episode **0** of season 5. Which makes "Mortal Khanbat" the **sixth** episode, albeit numbered "5".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell from your image, but [this review](https://www.denofgeek.com/us/tv/legends-of-tomorrow/286024/legends-of-tomorrow-season-5-episode-5-mortal-khanbat) indicates that he re-summoned the [Pùca](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/P%C3%B9ca) from Season 4.

> He’s trying every mystical solution he can find - bringing back a pooka from last season, making Nora’s kid come to the House of Mystery to wish him healthy again, shouting at archangels to cut a deal, something untoward with Ray’s foreskin. As each attempt fails, he lashes out harder and looks and acts more pathetically desperate. It’s so good, and so true to how I see the character in my head.

Quoting from the wiki entry:

[image: Image of the Pùca]

> **Healing**: they are able to heal injuries as one was shown to heal a wound on Constantine's forehead.

They are primarily [a creature of Celtic folklore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%BAca), and like many folklore creatures, their  powers vary considerably by the telling. In DC Comics, [Tawky Tawny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tawky_Tawny) has self-described as a Pooka before.